# How to ignore one exception in Camel while redelivering

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf

I have to implement an error handler that uses the Camel Redelivery Policy over a business process which send a SOAP request and process its response. During the process part, a special exception (RetryException) could be thrown. This exception is caught (thanks to onException(RetryException.class)) on the error handler level.
That was the easy part.

Now I want to ignore exceptions that could be thrown by the cxf endpoint (in case of connection error per example) and process them.
So I try :

- (1) One main route that has the onException clause with retry strategy
- (2) One sub route that aggregates 2 routes (and has noErrorHandler) to be sure to replay the 2 routes and not only the processing one that throw the exception :

  - (3) The route which send the SOAP request
  - (4) The route which process the response and can throw the retryException.

In order to ignore the exception thrown by the cxf endpoint I implement the route (3) like that :

```
public void configure() {
    from(ROUTE_NAME).
    .handleFault() // To handle Soap fault
    .onException(Fault.class)
        .continued(true)
        .end()
    .to("cxf:[...]")
    ;
}
```

It works like a charm, the response processor perform some checks before throwing the RetryException... But the continued instruction throws away all the informations about redelivery that I previously had and Camel believe that this exception is the first one. So the route enters into a kind of retry forever loop.

Exchange headers **before** onException(Fault) :

```
Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-ITEM-S28636-63117-1469800853403-0-1, CamelRedelivered=true, CamelRedeliveryCounter=1, CamelRedeliveryMaxCounter=2, operationName=[...]}
```

Exchange headers **after** onException(Fault) :

```
Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-ITEM-S28636-63117-1469800853403-0-1, operationName=[...]}
```

Did you have any solution to ignore some sub-route exception without erasing the upper route retry strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are connecting the routes via `direct` endpoint; if that's the case, I think your main issue is that you're marking `Fault` as continued which implies handled, which is most likely what's causing your redelivery headers to be cleared. You could try using `seda` or a message queue, just not the `direct` endpoint since it will basically link your routes into one.

Comment: Thanks That works but I've done in another way using doTry and doCatch.